# Формирование ответа в netty для HTTP запроса

Tags: java, http, request, netty, response

Написал простенький java-сервер с помощью netty 4.1.21.Final.

Сервер

```
public class SimpleServer extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(new SimpleServer());
                        // Кодек протокола HTTP
                        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                        // Собираем отдельные пакеты в полный http-запрос
                        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        ;

        ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind("localhost", 8080).sync();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    String message = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "    <head></head>\n" +
            "    <body>\n" +
            "        Test content\n" +
            "    </body>\n" +
            "</html>\n";

    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);

    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, buf);
    response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

    ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(response);
    ctx.channel().close();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.channel().close();
    }
}
```

Клиент

```
    public class SimpleClient  {

            public static

 void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
                bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
                bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
                bootstrap.handler(new ClientInitializer());

                ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect("localhost", 8080).sync();
                channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

            } finally {
                workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }

        private static class ClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) {
                channel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler());
            }
        }

        private static class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
            @Override
            public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                byte[] bytes = "Test request \n".getBytes();
                ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buf);
            }

            @Override
            public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
                while (byteBuf.isReadable()) {
                    System.out.print((char) byteBuf.readByte());
                    System.out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Всё работает хорошо. При обращении клиента или просто набираю в браузере localhost:8080 - получаю сформированный сервером ответ Test content с кодом 200.

Но не понимаю как ПРАВИЛЬНО сделать, чтобы в респонсе был json ответ. Просто new GSON.toJson(мойОбъект) и добавить в контент в виде строки?

Второй вопрос из той же серии - как правильно вернуть страницу html? Я видел образец https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServerIndexPage.html но неужели надо генерировать такую кучу кода? Как правильно это делают обычно?

Какие best practisies? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Netty - это очень низкоуровнево. Если вы хотите просто `Http` запросы - возьмите сервлеты - один класс, один метод и всё работает.

Comment: В будущем надо будет работать с кастомным протоколом и прикрутить соккеты. Поэтому смотрим на нетти. Как то же с ним работают люди? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто в методе `channelRead` преобразовать объект в строку и добавить к выводимым данным, но best practices - это сделать кодек:

```
class JsonCodec<T> extends MessageToMessageCodec<String, T> {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public JsonCodec(Class<String> inboundType, Class<T> outboundType) {
        super(inboundType, outboundType);
        this.clazz = outboundType;
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, T msg, List<Object> out)
      throws Exception {
        out.add(gson.toJson(msg));
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg, List<Object> out)
      throws Exception {
        out.add(gson.fromJson(msg, clazz));
    }
}
```

и добавить его в пайплайн между хэндлером или другим кодеком, возвращающим объекты, и кодеком или хэндлером, работающим со строками:

```
pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
pipeline.addLast(new RequestToStringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast(new StringToRequestEncoder());
pipeline.addLast(new JsonCodec<>(String.class, Person.class));
pipeline.addLast(new SomePersonHandler());
```

Если нужно вернуть статическую html-страницу, то можно так:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(htmlFile, "r");
boolean keepAlive = HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(request);

HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(request.protocolVersion(),
  HttpResponseStatus.OK);

response.headers()
        .set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
if (keepAlive) {
    response.headers()
            .set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, file.length());
    response.headers()
            .set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
}

ctx.write(response);

if (ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class) == null) {
    ctx.write(new DefaultFileRegion(file.getChannel(), 0, file.length()));
}
else {
    ctx.write(new ChunkedNioFile(file.getChannel()));
}

ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT);
if (!keepAlive)
    future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

Если динамическую, то ничто не мешает использовать какой-нибудь шаблонизатор, типа Thymeleaf. Скармливать ему шаблон и данные, получать строку html-кода и записывать её в канал.